# How to download image / pdf files from web service in spring applications

Tags: java, spring, rest, web, thymeleaf

@GetMapping(value = "/image", produces = "application/pdf")
    @ResponseBody
    public String downloadFile(@PathVariable("path") String path) throws IOException{
        ClassPathResource downloadLink = new ClassPathResource("/assets/"+path);

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + path);
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    headers.setContentLength(downloadLink.contentLength());
    Base64.getDecoder().decode(path);
    return "/admin/image";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i check your code your code is almost correct but you need to modify some piece of code, you can use this sample code for download file: you can refer this code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class DownloadFileRestController {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdf/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Calling Download:- " + fileName);
        ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("downloads/" + fileName);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        headers.setContentLength(pdfFile.contentLength());
        ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: Am getting a base64 string which i need to convert to file and render on the html page. i cant see the conversion in the code

Comment: you can send data after decoding : ` ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(new String (Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfFile.getInputStream().toString())), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
`